# How to add rows from Pandas to_sql db

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I am trying to get my dataframe to an sql database, but only the column names are being sent to the DB, the content (rows) of the DF is not on the DB.

What is missing?

```
today = datetime.datetime.today()
date = today.strftime("%Y%m%d")

conn = sqlite3.connect('G:\Drive\SQL\Wanted_DB.db')
c = conn.cursor()
conn.commit()

Data = pd.DataFrame([])

#here I add a bunch of lines on the Data DF

Data.to_sql('Data - '+date, conn, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

And I get the db file, with the name i wanted, but the rows of Data DF doesnt appear there.

What is missing?

Comment: Remove `+date` from `to_sql` command and try again.

Comment: It worked, thanks! Is there any way to add date to the table name?

Comment: I've known sqlite to lock - especially when not closing the connections properly. 
Have you tried with a fresh database, and ensured the connection was closed with `conn.close()` at the end of your script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by removing the Today and the '-'

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('G:\Drive\SQL\Wanted_DB.db')
c = conn.cursor()
conn.commit()

Data = pd.DataFrame([])

#here I add a bunch of lines on the Data DF

Data.to_sql('Data', conn, index=False, if_exists='append')
```